# Linux multinode: new comp or virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I want to learn more about Linux networking and administration.Also, plan to install Cassandra database on multiple nodes.Should I buy new computer or just go for virtual machines?What are pros and cons?

Proc

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               3000.000
CPU max MHz:           3500,0000
CPU min MHz:           800,0000
BogoMIPS:              6000.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Memory

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7914        2819        2195          46        2900        4912
Swap:          8127           0        8127
```

I have SSD.

Comment: If your goal is to learn more & fast  you can use virtual machines with network bridge between VM & host  or even if really motivated use a virtual machine as a router  :) for your virtual network :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide hardware information -- we can't decide whether it's better to buy new PC or use VM because we don't know whether your PC can run VM smoothly.
VM - Virtual Machine

Comment: Take a llok at my hardware specs.

Comment: A virtual machine should work there. Try it to see whether you're satisfied with how it works.